# If $f(x,u(x))$ measuable with conditions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

recently, I've encountered a question about measurable function. after I've searched in MSE, it's been asked in a similar way before, but curiously the answer is the same as I've considered to be wrong. the link is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926021/how-to-show-ft-ut-is-measurable), so what is the right answer?

copy the question as follows:

> Given $f(\cdot, y)$ is measurable for each $y$, $f(x, \cdot)$ is
>   continuous for each $x$. If $u(t)$ is continuous, how can I show that
>   the function $f:[0,1]\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(t, u(t))$ is
>   measurable?

The problem of the answer lies in "The continuous of $f$ is unknown", $f(x,u)$ is continuous only for specified $x$, not for all variables. Although the answer is correct in its own way, but no use for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put this into a little context, a function $f:\Omega\times \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(\cdot,a)$ is measurable for almost every $x\in\Omega$ and that $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous is call a *Caratheodory function*. This kind of function is commonly encountered in Calculus of Variation.

The proof usually goes like this: Let's define 
$$
g(x) := f(x,u(x)),
$$
where $u$ is a **simple function** 
$$
u(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \mathbf 1_{E_i}(x)
$$
where $E_i$ is a measurable set (I know $u$ is not continuous but please bear with me for a second). For any $t\in\Bbb R$, observe that 
$$
\{x\in\Omega : g(x)<t \} = \bigcup_{i=1}^m \{ x\in E_i : f(x,a_i)<t \}.
$$
Since we know that $x\mapsto f(x,a_i)$ is measurable, each set on the right hand side is measurable which implies that $g=f(\cdot,u(\cdot))$ is a measurable function.

In general, let $u$ be any **measurable function** then we can find a sequence $u_n$ of simple functions such that $u_n\to u$ almost everywhere. By continuity of $a\mapsto f(x,a)$ (almost every $x$), we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x,u_n(x)) = f(x,u(x)) = g(x)
$$
for almost every $x$. This shows that $g$ is a the (almost everywhere) limit of a sequence of measurable functions, hence $g$ is itself measurable.

The case where $u$ is **continuous** follows immediately.

Comment: +1 for your help, ok I also missed the almost everywhere convergence measurable function converges a measurable function, good tips in proving measurable function.

Comment: @LarryEppes Glad I could help :)

Comment: I checked again the condition in the beginning of your answer, I think $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous for almost every $x\in\Omega$ could be meaningful, and $f(\cdot, a)$ is measurable for all $a$. Am I right?

Comment: @LarryEppes Yes, they're the same conditions as the ones in your question.

Comment: I am searching on Caratheodory function and thinking about your final statement, when I reached https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393111/continuity-of-a-function-of-product-spaces, in the answer let $y=x \sin(1/x)$, it seem a counterexample of your final line.

Comment: I made a typo. What I wanted to consider is the case where $u$ is continuous, not $g$.

Comment: ok, yes, so $u(x)$ can be more general, i.e. $u(x)$ is measurable and finite uniformly in $\Omega$ to ensure that there is a sequence of simple function converges unoformly to $u$.